# How to read array values from function?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a simple Function to get and save values in array:

```
Function GetDataOwner()

 Dim DataOwner(2) As String

 DataOwner(0) = Sheets(1).Range("H21").Value
 DataOwner(1) = Sheets(1).Range("I21").Value
 DataOwner(2) = Sheets(1).Range("J21").Value


End Function
```

In other function, I would like read value:

```
Sub GenerateDB()

  Dim DataOwner() As String
  DataOwner = GetDataOwner()

  MsgBox DataOwner(1)
End Sub
```

But Excel say me error 13 type mismatch. I am novice with VBA function

Comment: You need to return the array from the `GetDataOwner` function:  `GetDataOwner = DataOwner` on the line above `End Function`

Answer (score 1):

**Soluce:**

```
Function GetDataOwner()

 Dim DataOwner(2) As String

 DataOwner(0) = Sheets(1).Range("H21").Value
 DataOwner(1) = Sheets(1).Range("I21").Value
 DataOwner(2) = Sheets(1).Range("J21").Value

 GetDataOwner = DataOwner
End Function


Sub GenerateDB()

  Dim DataOwner() As String
  DataOwner = GetDataOwner()

  MsgBox DataOwner(1)
End Sub
```

Thanks to @Comintern